# How to handle csv file with duplicate fieldnames when reading with csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv

I am working with a poorly-formed CSV file; it has duplicate fieldnames.

`csv.DictReader` just overwrites the first column with the same name with the contents of the second column with the same name. But I need both contents of columns with duplicate name.

I can't assign the `DictReader.fieldnames` parameter directly. There are about one hundred columns and every time it would be different number of columns, e.g.:

```
product, price1, price2, price1,...,price100
car, 100, 300, 200,...,350
```

output: `{'product':'car', 'price1': 200, 'price2':300}`

I need: `{'product':'car', 'price1': 100, 'price2':300, 'price3': 200}`

What is the way to do it?

Comment: You can specify the `fieldnames` yourself, but it's not wholly clear how you intend to deal with duplicates.

Comment: Why do you need to use a `DictReader()`? You can just stick to the regular reader if you fields don't actually map properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  thanks for suggestion. I'm new to Python and programming in general. Now it's clear to me I should use `csv.reader`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't use a `DictReader()` in this case. Stick to a regular reader instead.

You can always map to a dictionary based on a re-mapped list of fieldnames:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = remap(next(reader))
    for row in reader:
        row = dict(zip(fieldnames, row))
```

where the `remap()` function could either renumber your numbered columns or append extra information if column names are duplicated.

Re-numbering could be as easy as:

```
from itertools import count

def remap(fieldnames):
    price_count = count(1)
    return ['price{}'.format(next(price_count)) if f.startswith('price') else f
            for f in fieldnames]
```